# ± Symbol in text

Tags: symbols, packages

I can't get a `±` symbol to show up in my `.pdf` document, whether it be within a table, or in the main body of text. Can anyone offer any assistence ?

I have read everywhere it is `\pm` and would write as:

```
50\% \pm 2\%
```

or

```
50\% \pm{2\%}
```

As well as other variations.

Comment: `$\pm$` should work. But the usage of package `siunitx` package seems to be appropiate for such error ranges?

Comment: You also can type directly `±`, using `utf8` input encoding. However in the context, the best is to type `$50\,\%\pm 2\,\%$`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Similar to [Christian's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304157/36296), but `siunitx` will deal with the correct typesetting, be it text mode or math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  separate-uncertainty = true,
  multi-part-units = repeat
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
Math mode: $\SI{50 \pm 2}{\percent}$

Text mode: \SI{50 \pm 2}{\percent}
\end{document}
```

> [image: output]

Comment: Also one can use `+-` or `(..)` notation and `siunitx` would understand.

Answer (score 16):

`\pm` requires the mathmode, being switched into with `$...$`. For displaying `%` use `\SI{number}{\percent}`  rather for better spacing and correct usage of fonts.

For text mode, there's `\textpm` too, this requires `textcomp` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
$\SI{50}{\percent} \pm \SI{2}{\percent}$

Textmode: \SI{50}{\percent} \textpm\ \SI{2}{\percent}
\end{document}
```

[image]